# Apt-get Java JRE Errors

Tags: 14.04, apt, java

I'm a bit new to Ubuntu and Linux in general, and haven't been able to get used to a few things. When I'm trying to use apt-get to remove packages, I'm given this:

```
After this operation, 90.1 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 207189 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing cowsay (3.03+dfsg1-6) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up jre1.8.0-101 (1.8.0101-1) ...
Error: unpack200 - command could not be found.

Please refer to the Troubleshooting section of theInstallation Instructions
on the download page.
update-alternatives: error: alternative path /usr/java/jre1.8.0_101/bin/java doesn't exist
dpkg: error processing package jre1.8.0-101 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 jre1.8.0-101
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

And to install, I get this:

```
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up jre1.8.0-101 (1.8.0101-1) ...
Error: unpack200 - command could not be found.

Please refer to the Troubleshooting section of theInstallation Instructions
on the download page.
update-alternatives: error: alternative path /usr/java/jre1.8.0_101/bin/java doesn't exist
dpkg: error processing package jre1.8.0-101 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 jre1.8.0-101
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

When I call java -version, I get:

```
java version "1.8.0_101"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_101-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.101-b13, mixed mode)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: "Please refer to the Troubleshooting section of the Installation Instructions
on the download page." looks like a hint to me ;)

Comment: I had a look earlier. I'm still confused on the whole thing as I'm relatively new to Ubuntu.

Comment: I found a reference where unpack200 is said to be for the install of the 32-bit version and not the 64-bit but that should not be the issue here...

Comment: I was able to install java 1.8 by using sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer, and that is stored in another directory than the jre that the shell is trying to access